# Can't fix the calculate module on my BMI calculator

Tags: python

```
def main():
  intro()
  GetWeight()
  GetHeight()
  Calculate()

def intro():
  print ("Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rabucc")
  def GetWeight():
  weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
  return weight

def GetHeight():
  height = input("Enter your height in inches:\n ")
  return height

def Calculate():
  height = GetHeight()
  weight = GetWeight()
  BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
  print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()
```

I have revised the code over and over trying to get rid of this error. Sorry if this something really simple I am trying to teach myself. Thank you for looking.

```
line 25, in Calculate
BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'
```

After revising the code I now have

```
def main():
intro()
GetWeight()
GetHeight()
Calculate()

def intro():
print ("Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rufus Hunt")

def GetWeight ():
weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
return weight

def GetHeight ():
height = float(input("Enter your height in inches:\n "))
return height

def Calculate ():
height = GetHeight()
weight = GetWeight()
BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()
```

This causes the program to repeat the two questions and then calculate the BMI. Why is it repeating the questions?

Comment: Just a note, in Python, a module is a file, your `Calculate` is a function.

Comment: Also, this shouldn't even be runnalbe as you have no indent after `def GetWeight()`

Comment: Another also: You call `GetWeight` and `GetHeight` in both `Calculate` and `intro`

Comment: So each defined function should be remade as it's own file? Giving me 4 files for the program correct? Can I just copy/paste the sections into their own file as is or is more needed? Also how can I fix the calculate function to use the values entered by the user for the equation?

Comment: No, I just mean that you shouldn't refer to your functions as modules.

Comment: When I fix the indentation, this runs smoothly.  It doesn't work properly, as it insists that I enter my weight and height twice each, but it runs.

Comment: You don't need to call `GetWeight` and `GetHeight` from within `intro`.  `Calculate` already calls them.

Comment: Are you sure your actual code does not have `weight = GetWeight` somewhere, i.e. without `()`? _That_ would explain the error you are reporting.

Comment: `def main():  
    intro()  
    GetWeight()  
    GetHeight()  
    Calculate()  

def intro():  
    print ("Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rabucc")  

def GetWeight ():
  weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
  return weight

def GetHeight ():
  height = float(input("Enter your height in inches:\n "))
  return height

def Calculate ():
  height = GetHeight
  weight = GetWeight
  BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
  print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()`
This is the complete code @tobias_k

Comment: @RABucc Don't put code in comments. Edit your original question to include the relevant code. Make sure it is properly formatted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `GetHeight` method you aren't casting to a float, similar to what you did in your `GetWeight` method:

Change this:

```
height = input("Enter your height in inches:\n ")
```

to this:

```
height = float(input("Enter your height in inches:\n "))
```

Also, extra info, you can remove calling `GetWeight` and `GetHeight` inside your `main`. Your `Calculate` method is already taking care of this for you at these lines:

```
height = GetHeight()
weight = GetWeight()
```

So, code will be:

```
def main():
  intro()
  Calculate()

def intro():
  print ("Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rabucc")
  def GetWeight():
  weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
  return weight

def GetHeight():
  height = float(input("Enter your height in inches:\n "))
  return height

def Calculate():
  height = GetHeight()
  weight = GetWeight()
  BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
  print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()
```

Demo:

```
Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rabucc
Enter your height in inches:
 5
How much do you weigh in pounds?
 5
Your BMI is 140.6
```

Comment: While this in _one_ problem with the code, it would not produce the error message OP is reporting.

Comment: @tobias_k The code is running fine for my on Python 3.4 after that modification. What's happening on your end?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have made the change, but I still can't get the program to calculate BMI. How do I fix the calculate section?

Comment: It sure would (did not try), but OP seems to get a different error, so there seems be be something wrong with the question.

Comment: @idjaw when I run it with the change I still get the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'` error. I am using 3.5.1

Comment: I copy pasted your code (fixed the indentation error), and added float to the height and it is working. Beyond this, I have no idea what else is wrong.

Comment: Awesome @idjaw I made the changes and now the program works as it should! Now I need to convert this into a modualized program. Can you guys help with that here or should I make a new post?

Answer (score 1):

A cleaned-up version:

```
def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def bmi(weight, height):
    return 703. * weight / height**2

def main():
    print("Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rabucc")
    weight = get_float("How much do you weigh (in pounds)? ")
    height = get_float("How tall are you (in inches)? ")
    print("Your BMI is {:.1f}".format(bmi(weight, height)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to not indent the GetWeight function definition.  Indentation matters for Python.  Try this.

```
def main():
  intro()
  Calculate()

def intro():
  print ("Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rabucc")

def GetWeight():
  weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
  return weight

def GetHeight():
  height = float(input("Enter your height in inches:\n "))
  return height

def Calculate():
  height = GetHeight()
  weight = GetWeight()
  BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
  print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()
```

Comment: Convert height to a float too

Comment: Based on the OP's original error, I think the indentation was because of a copy paste issue. I don't think OP is seeing that in their editor.

Comment: Wouldnt that indentation cause GetWeight not to be properly declared, resulting in weight = GetWeight() assigning a function to weight, rather than an integer?  That would explain the error message.

Comment: The bad indentation would give exactly that: Indentation error. I'm pretty sure OP made a spacing bug when porting code to their question.

Comment: Ah well, that may be.  The code works fine (other than multiple calls to get weight and height) so maybe the question is not well worded.  So be it.

Comment: @BryanShaw Only if `GetWeight` returned a reference to itself (or another function), which it does not.

Comment: OK thanks, @tobias_k.  I still have some Python learnin to do.  I thought that if you assigned a function that wasn't defined it would make assumptions with regards to type since Python is so type... fluid.

Comment: Sorry @BryanShaw this is my first day learning on python and I apologize for any confusion I may have caused.

Comment: No problem, @RABucc.  Just trying to figure out how to help you is all.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
  intro()
  weight = GetWeight()
  height = GetHeight()
  Calculate(weight, height)

def intro():
  print ("Welcome to the BMI Calculator by Rabucc")

def GetWeight():
  weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
  return weight

def GetHeight():
  height = input("Enter your height in inches:\n ")
  return height

def Calculate(lb,inches):
  BMI = (lb * 703) / (lb * inches)
  print ("Your BMI is", BMI)

main()
```